# .htaccess query string with static page

Tags: .htaccess

So, unfortunately I'm using vBulletin with Kohana and my integration is getting a bit complicated locking vBulletin out.  Doing some rewrites, this in particular:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^do=(editprofile|editoptions)$
RewriteRule ^forum/profile.php$ /user_profile/edit/ [R=301,L]
```

Comes back with `/user_profile/edit/?do=editprofile`

where I need `/user_profile/edit/`

Comment: Looks like the QSA flag is auto added ... Ps. when redirecting use http:// style url.

Answer (score 1):

Append a `?` to clear the query string.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^do=(editprofile|editoptions)$
RewriteRule ^forum/profile.php$ /user_profile/edit/? [R=301,L]
```